# How can I iterate through a dictionary in React to get the values separately and display using html?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, loops, dictionary

I have a modal that I want to display validation from my backend controller to the user.  errors is a dictionary with string keys and array values.  I am using React and setting the validation errors as state.  I can log these errors to my console.  But am not able to get them to display on the UI.  This is how I am using state:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState<string[]>([]);
```

When I do this

```
console.log(Object.entries(errors).map(([key, value]) => value));
```

This is what is printed to the console. [image]

How can I further iterate through this to display each error separately in the UI?   Within my modal, I tried doing

```
<div className="modal">
                {
                    errors.length > 0 && (
                        Object.entries(errors).map(([key, value]) => { return <div>{value}</div>})
                    )
                }
                <label>First Name: </label>
```

But this doesn't display anything.  I think I need to pull out each string individually and display it in a paragraph but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output of `console.log(Object.entries(errors).map(([key, value]) => value));`, your `errors` variable looks either like this:

```
const errors = [
  ["required something", "invalid"],
  ["some other stuff", "required"]
];
```

or like this:

```
const errors = {
  error1: ["required something", "invalid"],
  error2: ["some other stuff", "required"]
};
```

Your default value of `[]` tempts to believe that it's the former, but your use of `Object.entries` suggests the latter.

The reason it's important is, among other things, because of this condition: `errors.length > 0`

So I will address both scenarios. Let's say that your `errors` variable is the former case, which is an array. Then to render it, you would simply do this:

```
 {errors.length > 0 &&
     errors.map(([key, value]) => {
          return <div key={key}>{key}</div>;
   })}
```

If, however, the `errors` variable is an object as in the latter case, then you would render it like so:

```
{Object.entries(errors).length > 0 &&
    Object.entries(errors).map(([key, value]) => {
       return <div key={value[0]}>{value[0]}</div>;
  })}
```

Comment: thank you for your response.  I tried both and am getting this warning Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.  The later is how it is set up. const errors = {
  error1: ["required something", "invalid"],
  error2: ["some other stuff", "required"]
};  Does this have to change: const [errors, setErrors] = useState<string[]>([]);

Comment: @dev_in_training This warning has nothing to do with how you render these errors. It's a different problem. Post your entire component's code and I will take a look.

Comment: Actually, it is working.  I think it was getting stuck in my debugger.  Thank you so much.  The second answer worked!

Comment: @dev_in_training no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

every time your App uses 'setErrors' , Render is called and rerender happened.check if your App exceeds limitation of rendering or not .